# Solved: Braintree and Magestore Onestepcheckout setData() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

we use magestore onestepcheckout 3.5.0 on magento 1.9 with braintree payment integrated. In backend module you can set admin notification email and you can put more than one address separated by a coma ( **,** ) but there is an error on function that manage this send that thrown in this exception:

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to a member function setData() on a non-object (array)' in app/code/community/Gene/Braintree/Block/Paypal/Info.php:71
```

So you have to change the file **Magestore/Onestepcheckout/Model/Observer.php** row 313

```
 foreach ($sendTo as $recipient) {
                $result = $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $_order->getStoreId()))
                        ->sendTransactional(
                        $template, Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/order/identity', $_order->getStoreId()), $recipient['email'], $recipient['name'], array(
                    'order' => $_order,
                    'billing' => $_order->getBillingAddress(),
                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlock->toHtml(),
                        )
                );
            }
```

with

```
 
// Added
$paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml()

foreach ($sendTo as $recipient) {
                $result = $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $_order->getStoreId()))
                        ->sendTransactional(
                        $template, Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/order/identity', $_order->getStoreId()), $recipient['email'], $recipient['name'], array(
                    'order' => $_order,
                    'billing' => $_order->getBillingAddress(),
                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                        )
                );
            }
```